# Google search does not show images with advanced searches in Firefox

Tags: firefox, images, search, google-search

Every time I do an advanced search like, glossier "lidstar" review or use any other advanced command such as AND or OR I only get a few or sometimes zero image results. In the "all" section of the search results it shows that there are more images, but when I click to see them they don't appear. I'm using Firefox Quantum with the most recent update.

I've cleared the cache and cookies ect.
I've done virus and malware scans, but nothing was found.
I've restarted my computer and started Firefox in both private and safe mode.

Nothing has helped. This just started happening all of a sudden last night. I haven't downloaded or installed anything. I'd really appreciate any help with this.

Comment: You write of only Firefox - does that mean that it works in a different browser? Have you tried restarting your modem/router?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I can try internet explorer and I'll try resetting the monitor. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: No, unfortunately, neither method worked.

Comment: How about other search engines, such as DuckDuckGo?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That seems to be working correctly, but I don't use it that often. I don't know if there's a way to search for an exact phrase. If there is then I could tell you if I'm getting the same image results that I'm getting on Google.